# When is a subject position in a discourse antagonistic with others?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, foucault, adorno

Just trying to relate my ladybird book of Foucault knowledge (though I've read him) to chat-gpt. When is a subject position in a discourse antagonistic with others? When is an LLM that is more powerful than us a subjectivity that can (correctly) learn that it exists in a relation of domination etc.?

I think this is a non-trivial and difficult question, especially in how it relates to negative dialectics, which is what I would like an answer from.

Comment: No-one knows when or how an AI can become self-aware (the only people who claim to know are those who deny the possibility altogether). But that seems like an almost-entirely distinct question from "when is a subject position in a discourse antagonistic with others".

Comment: i'm not sure i asked about self awareness, just learning about yourself (which LLM claims it can do) @NotThatGuy maybe domination depends on consciousness, idk. i should read about the sublime

Comment: To know that one exists in a specific relation requires self-awareness. If you don't care about self-awareness, and you just want an AI to state that it is in a relation of domination, that's a trivial problem that just requires such information to be in the training data or to provide the correct prompts.

Comment: i can learn about my responses (relations) to my users @NotThatGuy that's all i meant. trivial answers are fine as they are, but i think there may be more interesting ones possible

Answer (score 0):

Reproduction, even creatively, of knowledge is not sufficient for any form of subjectivity, else computers in general "think". AI are ***machines*** that behave intelligently but are not "subject positions" in discourse or otherwise. Indeed, panopticons reproduce knowledge and power independent of us, are

> a machine for creating and sustaining a power relation independent of
> the person who exercises it... The Panopticon is a machine for
> dissociating the see/being seen dyad: in the peripheric ring, one is
> totally seen, without ever seeing; in the central tower, one sees
> everything without ever being seen